# How to do a specific action depending on the file extension of a command-line argument

Tags: c, parameters, program-entry-point

I want to have a program with specific arguments of different types. For example I start my program like this:

```
./program picture.jpg image.jpg

./program picture.ppm image.jpg
```

Now I want my program to recognize the different extensions,  `jpg` vs `ppm`. How can I easily do it? I tried:

```
if (argv[1][-3] == j)
{
     //do something
}
...
```

But this is not working and I can't find any reply on my question on internet (probably, because I am asking badly...).

btw. I am python programmer and I am learning c...

Comment: Try `argv[1][strlen(argv[1])-3]`, negative indices do not work this way in c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test the 3rd character counting from the end you can use:

`if(argv[1][strlen(argv[1])-3] == 'j')`.

Note that this method will cause undefined behaviour if the length of  the argument is lower than 3.

You can safeguard this by using `if(strlen(argv[1]) > 3 && argv[1][strlen(argv[1])-3] == 'j')`

Comment: @no_named_nobody Oh, ok. For the solution use argument lenght - 3 to find the 3rd character counting from the end, edited the post.

Comment: @Ctx, they are, thanks for the heads up, looks like you already gave the answer.

Comment: No, I just gave a comment, you give the answer, which I just voted up.

Comment: One minor addition: Since the OP wants to test for a char, it looks like he wants `'j'` instead of `j`

Comment: Note that this solution leads to undefined behavior for command line arguments with length less than 3.

Answer (score 1):

You should

- Check the count of argument from `argc`.
- Loop over each command line argument by using `argv[i]`, where `i` is from `1` to `argc-1`.
- make use of [`strstr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) to check if the `.jpg` or `.ppm` is present in any of the strings pointer to by `argv[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to find the (last) extension in a filename is to use the standard library function [`strrchr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strrchr.3p.html).

The following checks whether the extension of the first command-line argument is `.jpg` or `.jpeg` or some upper-case version (like `.JPG` or `.Jpeg`). It assumes that you have already ensured that `argv[1]` is valid by checking the value of `argc`.

```
char* extension = strrchr(argv[1], '.');
if (extension &&
    (0 == strcasecmp(extension, ".jpg")
     || 0 == strcasecmp(extension, ".jpeg"))) {
  /* Handle jpegs */
}
else {
  /* Try something else */
}
```

In practice, you would probably wrap that into a function which returned some kind of `enum` representing the known extension types, so that you could use it with various arguments, not just the first one. You would also want to have some way to let the user manually specify a type, in case they wanted to call your program with a badly-named file.

A couple of usage notes:

1. Like `strlen()`, `strrchr()` must scan every byte in its argument. So avoid calling it more than once on the same string. If you'll need the result more than once, save it in a temporary.
2. If the filename doesn't contain the delimiter (in this case, `.`), `strrchr` returns `NULL`. If you attempt to use the return value without checking for this case, your program is likely to crash (and is certain to invoke Undefined Behaviour). So always check the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Python where a negative array index means to start indexing from the end, a negative array index in C counts backward from the *start*, so that's not what you want.

You can use the `strstr` function to search for ".jpg" or ".ppm" in the string, or use `strlen` to get the length of the string and start looking at that index -3.